# Move object by Bezier Curve, combine with Rotation

Tags: java, android, rotation, andengine, bezier

My engine (AndEngine) provides the modifier to move an object by Bezier Curve path, just by providing 3 or 4 points co-ordinate.

In my game, I move some birds with determined 3 points. However, it looks fake because the birds always point to a direction.

This looks like a mathematical question, but I think I should post at StackOverflow instead of Math Exchange: How to determine the rotation angle (in radian or degree) for the birds at a time?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent That will probably help you alot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will take two points say P1 and P2 and will find the angle between them and then rotate you bird on that angle

```
    deltaX = nextPointX - YourBirdX;
    deltaY = NextPointY - YourBirdY;
    degree = ((Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX)));
    angle = degree * 180 / 3.14;

    if(angle<0)
    {
        angle = 360+angle;
    }
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: float angleRad =(float)Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX);     
float Vx = 50* (float)Math.cos(angleRad);
float Vy = 50 * (float)Math.sin(angleRad);
body.setVelocity(vX,vY);

Answer (score 0):

What about `(bezier(path, position + epsilon) - bezier(path, position)) / epsilon`? Or, if you want it without the epsilon, look up the *first derivation of a bezier curve*.

Comment: I don't know anything about Bezier Curve! I just input 3 points co-ordianates, and the engine does the rest, so I have no idea what are they.

Comment: can u please help me?with this question realated to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18651025/how-to-move-image-on-curve-on-touch-event-in-android